# array of strings within a struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

Say we have,

```
typedef struct{
    char* ename;
    char** pname;
}Ext;

Ext ext[5];
```

What I am trying to do is to populate the data as following:

```
ext[0].ename="XXXX";
ext[0].pname={"A", "B", "C"};  // and so on for the rest of the array
```

-- I am pretty sure this is not the right way of doing this because I am getting errors. Please let me know the correct way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: Also, are you trying to statically allocate a large number of such structs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first assignment is correct.

The second one is not. You need to dynamically allocate the array:

```
ext[0].pname = malloc( sizeof(char*) * 5 );
ext[0].pname[0] = "A";
ext[0].pname[1] = "B";
//and so on
//you can use a loop for this
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't mention what compiler you are using.  If it is C99-compliant, then the following should work:

```
   const char *a[] = {"A", "B", "C"}; // no cast needed here
   const char **b;
   void foo(void) {
       b = (const char *[]){"A", "B", "C"}; // cast needed
   }
```

Your arrays being within a typedef'd struct is irrelevant here.

---

**Edit:** (nine years later). My answer is ***wrong:*** the compound literal in `foo()` is created on the stack (aka automatic storage), and so the above code is incorrect. See e.g. [Lifetime of referenced compound array literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14955194/318716), and see [Initializing variables with a compound literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47263725/318716).

In contrast, this code snippet is fine:

```
   const char *a[] = {"A", "B", "C"}; // no cast needed here
   const char **b = (const char *[]){"A", "B", "C"}; // cast needed
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for saving me some headache.

Comment: why is the cast needed in this case?