# Lifetime of referenced compound array literals

Tags: c, compound-literals

I only recently learned that I can actually use references to compound literal arrays in C, which I find useful, but I don't quite understand how it works.

For instance, say that I use the feature to avoid having to declare a variable for a call some socket interface function where I don't care about the return name length, like this:

```
int sockfamily(int fd)
{
    struct sockaddr_storage ss;

    getpeername(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&ss, (socklen_t [1]){sizeof(ss)});
    return(ss.ss_family);
}
```

Clearly, `sizeof(ss)` needs to actually be stored on the stack in order for a pointer to it to be passed to `getpeername`, and space on the stack must therefore be allocated and reserved for that purpose, but what is the lifetime of this allocation? How long can I trust it to remain allocated?

Looking at the assembly output of GCC, I observe that if I put the call to `getpeername` in a loop, the allocation does not survive for multiple iterations of the loop, but what other conditions, then, might cause it to cease to exist?

Comment: For struct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882564/what-is-the-lifetime-of-compound-literals-passed-as-arguments/31178926#31178926

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A *compound literal* defined within a function has automatic lifetime associated with the block that contains it (i.e. the same lifetime as a variable declared on the same level).  This is specified in the standard, paragraph 6.5.2.5p5.

```
int f() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        int *j = (int []){i};  // storage duration of loop body
    }
}
```

This essentially means that a compound literal is equivalent to a variable declared and initialized in the same scope:

```
int f() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        int __unnamed[] = {i};
        int *j = __unnamed;
    }
}
```

Take care if passing compound literals anywhere their pointers could persist past their lifetime:

```
int f() {
    int *p;
    if (1) {
        p = (int []){0, 1, 2};
        assert(p[0] == 0);
    }
    // *p is undefined
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the standard! That is very helpful.

Comment: Given something like `void blah(void) { struct foo *f; ... foo = somefunc(); if (foo==NULL) f=(struct foo*){data}; ...}` would there be any clean way to have the `if` control more than one statement?

Comment: @supercat if I understand correctly, you could try something like `struct foo *fallback[] = {data}; if (f==NULL) f=fallback;` - but then you wouldn't need a compound literal.

Comment: @ecatmur: That's my point. I see no way to have compound literals behave as lvalues without introducing semantic difficulties, *except* in cases where they can be (and are) made `const static`.  I wonder how much real-world code would be broken if the standard were changed such that compound literals would be `const static` lvalues if all their members were constants, and could otherwise be regarded as rvalues [with compilers being allowed to have the latter situations yield temporary lvalues, but with such use being deprecated]?

Comment: @ecatmur: For the scenario where the type does not contain a VLA, but the values are non-constant, I could see some usefulness to having compound literals be lvalues which are (for purposes of lifetime) hoisted to *function scope*, but having them be lvalues of shorter lifetime seems to me like a worst-of-all-worlds solution.  Being able to define `const static` items other than strings within a macro would be represent semantics not otherwise obtainable and shouldn't be hard for a compiler (the handling would be basically equivalent to that of a string literal).

Comment: @ecatmur: I suspect the reason gcc's statement-within-expression extension didn't get adopted into the Standard is that some compilers may have trouble creating automatic-duration lvalues within an expression context; defining a standard means for compilers that can create automatic lvalues mid-expression to let programmers define named variables there would seem more useful than having compound literals behave as anonymous local variables.