# What is the lifetime of compound literals passed as arguments?

Tags: c, struct, compound-literals

This compiles without warnings using clang.

```
typedef struct {
  int option;
  int value;
} someType;

someType *init(someType *ptr) {
  *ptr = (someType) {
    .option = ptr->option | ANOTHEROPT,
    .value = 1
  };

  return ptr;
}

int main()
{
  someType *typePtr = init( &(someType) {
    .option = SOMEOPT
  });
  // do something else with typePtr
}
```

1. Is this even valid C?
2. If so: What is the lifetime of the compound literal?

Comment: If you knew the name of what you were using did you attempt to research the feature. These two excellent pieces come up 1 and 2 for me: [The New C: Compound Literals](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404) and [6.25 Compound Literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) and they both answer your question.

Comment: I have read those (and several more), but didn't find this specific example anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's valid C in C99 or above.

> #### C99 §6.5.2.5 *Compound literals*
>
> The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the
> initializer list. If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object
> has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
> the enclosing block.

In your example, the compound literal has automatic storage, which means, its lifetime is within its block, i.e, the `main()` function that it's in.

Recommended reading from @Shafik Yaghmour:

1. [The New C: Compound Literals](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404)
2. [GCC Manual: 6.25 Compound Literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)

Answer (score 4):

Yu Hao has answered with the standard, now some vulgarization.

Whenever you see a compound literal like:

```
struct S *s;
s = &(struct S){1};
```

you can replace it with:

```
struct S *s;
struct S __HIDDEN_NAME__ = {1};
s = &__HIDDEN_NAME__;
```

So:

main.c

```
#include <assert.h>

struct S {int i;};
/* static: lives for the entire program. */
struct S *s1 = &(struct S){1};
struct S *s2;
struct S *s3;
struct S *s4;

int f(struct S *s) {
    return s->i + 1;
}

int main() {
    /* Undefined behaviour: not defined yet.
     * GCC 10 -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 gives at runtime:
     * runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct S' */
#if 0
    assert(f(s2) == 1);
#endif

    /* Lives inside main, and any function called from main. */
    s2 = &(struct S){1};
    /* Fine because now instantiated. */
    assert(f(s2) == 2);

    /* Only lives in this block. */
    {
        s3 = &(struct S){1};
        /* Fine. */
        assert(f(s3) == 2);
    }
    {
        /* On GCC 10 -O0, this replaces s3 above due to UB */
        s4 = &(struct S){2};
    }
    /* Undefined Behavior: lifetime has ended in previous block.
     * On GCC 10, ubsan does not notice it, and the assert fails
     * due to the s4 overwrite.*/
#if 0
    assert(s3->i == 1);
#endif
}
```

Full compilation command:

```
gcc -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c
```

Comment: If you ever update the example, for clarity please rename the variables to s1 (global), s2 (main) and s3 (sub-block).  The last comment doesn't seem right to me as I think you mean to refer to s3 which is indeed is out of scope, but it would reference s2 (and s1 is shadowed).

Comment: Beautiful.  The s4 case you added is interesting, and really surprising, what do you mean with "replaces s3"?  If it had the same name (s3) I could see it but why would there be any interacting between two different variables (s3 and s4)?  Why do you use the function f opposed to just test the values directly?  The last assert doesn't use f(), not sure if if that was on purpose or an oversight.

Comment: @AllanWind s3 and s4 go on stack, after s3 deallocates stack goes down, then s4 goes in the same location, O0 is really dumb and predictable. `f` was used in random places to show that lifetime stays for subcalls (kind of obvious because on stack).