# Static initialization of array of struct A, where struct A contains a pointer to array of struct B (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Given the following typedefs:

```
// Structures for kana to romaji conversion lookup
typedef struct {
  const u16 kana; // Kana codepoint
  const char* romaji;
} KanaSuffix;

typedef struct {
  // Kana codepoint is implied by position in array
  const char* romaji;
  const KanaSuffix* suffixes;
} KanaPrefix;
```

Is it possible to initialize an array of `KanaPrefix` statically in a single step, where some elements of the array have `suffixes` pointing to a static array of `KanaSuffix`?

Now I'm doing this:

```
const KanaSuffix KANA_SUFFIXES_KI[] = {
  { 0x3030, "kya" },
  { 0x3032, "kyo" }
};

const KanaPrefix KANA_TO_ROMAJI[] = {
  { NULL, NULL },
  { "a", NULL },
  { "ki", KANA_SUFFIXES_KI }
};
```

But I want to do something more like this:

```
const KanaPrefix KANA_TO_ROMAJI[] = {
  { NULL, NULL },
  { "a", NULL },
  { "ki", {
    { 0x3030, "kya" },
    { 0x3032, "kyo" }
  } }
};
```

Comment: Will every `KanaPrefix` have the same number of `KanaSuffix`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
const KanaPrefix KANA_TO_ROMAJI[] = {
  { NULL, NULL },
  { "a", NULL },
  { "ki",  (KanaSuffix [2]) {
      { 0x3030, "kya" },
      { 0x3032, "kyo" }
    }
  }
};
```

**EDIT**:

I can [now] confirm this is defined behaviour, since the lifetime [or duration] of that **compound literal** is the same as of static storage:

> C99 §6.5.2.5 Compound literals
>
> The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object
>   initialized by the initializer list. If the compound literal occurs
>   **outside the body of a function**, the object has static storage
>   duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
>   the enclosing block.

References:

[What is the lifetime of compound literals passed as arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882564/what-is-the-lifetime-of-compound-literals-passed-as-arguments#21882652)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that looks good! Looking at this on my phone now but will try it out when I get home.

Answer (score 6):

If all you need is a static object, then you can use compound literals, since if defined outside of a function scope, have static storage duration.

Of course since the member `suffixes` of the struct `KanaPrefix` is pointing to more than one element you will need to store the count too:

```
typedef struct {
  const char* romaji;
  const KanaSuffix* suffixes;
  const size_t count;   
} KanaPrefix;

const KanaPrefix KANA_TO_ROMAJI[] = {
  { NULL, NULL , 0 },
  { "a", NULL , 0 },
  { "ki", ( KanaSuffix[2] ){ //this is a compound literal
    { 0x3030, "kya" },
    { 0x3032, "kyo" }
  } , 2 }  //count is here
};
```

Comment: You can do the compound literal w/o the index `{ "ki", ( KanaSuffix[] ) {`, and great catch of the count.

Comment: @bsa I don't recommend that. You should use a macro for the value with some meaningful name and use it on both the compound literal and the count member.

Comment: @2501 Is it non-standard? What's the reason you don't recommend it?

Comment: @2501 I see.. I guess because it acts as a built-in compile-time check that the length matches the count right? I'm actually generating the definition automatically, so a mistake is unlikely, but it will still help to guard against mistakes in my generation code, or future hand modifications. Thanks!